# Issues Migrating Drupal 8.9.13 to 9.0.1

Tags: drupal, drupal-9

I am attempting to update from 8.9.13 to 9.0.1 (intending to migrate to 9 in general, not specifically 9.0.1)

Its on a composer site.

I'm running:

```
composer require drupal/core:^9.0.1  drupal/core-dev:^9.0.1 --update-with-all-dependencies
```

I keep running up against the following errors:

```
Problem 1
    - drupal/loft_data_grids is locked to version 1.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - drupal/loft_data_grids 1.3.0 requires drupal/core ~8.0 -> found drupal/core[8.0.0-beta6, ..., 8.9.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9.0.1).
  Problem 2
    - drupal/upgrade_status is locked to version 3.4.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - drupal/upgrade_status 3.4.0 requires drupal/core ^8.7.0 -> found drupal/core[8.7.0-alpha1, ..., 8.9.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^9.0.1).
  Problem 3
    - drupal/backup_migrate is locked to version 5.0.0-rc2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process[v4.4.0-BETA1] | install symfony/process[v3.4.39] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v3.4.39 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 9.1.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.4.0-BETA2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.4.0-RC1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.4.0 (conflict analysis result)
.... remvoed for brevity of symfony/profess v4.4.1 - 4.4.2 - etc until 4.4.19
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v4.4.19 (conflict analysis result)
    - drupal/recaptcha 3.0.0 requires drupal/captcha ^1.0.0-alpha1 -> satisfiable by drupal/captcha[1.1.0].
    - drupal/recaptcha is locked to version 3.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - drush/drush is locked to version 10.3.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - drupal/captcha 1.1.0 requires drupal/core ^8.8 || ^9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[9.0.1, ..., 9.2.x-dev].
    - drupal/core[9.0.1, ..., 9.2.x-dev] require symfony/process ^4.4 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v4.4.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process 4.4.x-dev (conflict analysis result)
```

Could anyone help enlighten me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carefully read the problem statements, for **Problem 1**:

```
- drupal/loft_data_grids 1.3.0 requires drupal/core ~8.0
```

This indicates that [Loft Data Grids](https://www.drupal.org/project/loft_data_grids) has a constraint to Drupal 8.x, hence the error. When you follow the link, you will also see that that project doesn't have a Drupal 9 release, so that is blocking your upgrade already. Try and apply the patches from either [Drupal 9 Readiness](https://www.drupal.org/project/loft_data_grids/issues/3145227) or [Automated Drupal 9 compatibility fixes](https://www.drupal.org/project/loft_data_grids/issues/3147959).

The same applies to **Problem 2** [Upgrade Status](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status), though you wouldn't need this module in Drupal 9, so consider removing this one before upgrading:

```
- drupal/upgrade_status 3.4.0 requires drupal/core ^8.7.0
```

I advice you first to fix the module constraints in general that are not yet ready for Drupal 9 before even attempting to run the Composer upgrade command to Drupal 9, as they will all halt the upgrade in similar way.

Please see [Apply Drupal 9 compatibility patches with Composer](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/apply-drupal-9-compatibility-patches-composer) and [Require v8 only contrib module with v9 patch](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296802/require-v8-only-contrib-module-with-v9-patch) to get around Drupal 8 modules that aren't tagged yet with a Drupal 9 release, but have a patch that can be applied.

Comment: Thanks for this @baikho. I have applied the patches for LDG that you linked to, had to do by hand as it was failing due to composer. I'm still getting the same error. Do I need to delete composer.lock or anything like that to allow it to continue?